# Deleting blank lines with Python

Tags: python, string, text

I have a text file composed of two columns that I want to plot against each other. I need to remove the last blank line from the text file.

I have tried a variety of things, such as this:

```
file = open('test3.dat')
lines = file.readlines()
lines = lines[:-1]
w = open('test3.dat','w')
w.writelines([item for item in lines[:-1]])
w.close()
```

And this:

```
file = open('test3.dat')
lines = file.readlines() 
w = open('test3.dat','w')
del lines[-1] 
w.writelines(lines)
w.close()
```

Yet I always end up with one last blank line. What am I missing?

Update: 
This deletes the second column in my file, and transposes the first one - aka now my file is just a single line with the values of what used to be the first column. Any additional help is appreciated!

```
import fileinput
lines = [line.strip() for line in fileinput.FileInput('test3.dat') ]
open('test3.dat','w').writelines(lines)
w.close()
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Is some other code complaining about the "blank line"?

Comment: In linux, a blank line is recommended to have at the end of a file. See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file)

Comment: @AstroLorraine Did I answer your question? If so, would you mind accepting it? (Click on the checkmark next to my answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all blank lines, you can do this:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines() if len(line.strip()) != 0]
```

To remove just the final blank lines, do this:

```
pos = len(lines) - 1
while pos >= 0 and len(lines[pos].strip()) == 0:
  pos -= 1
lines = lines[:pos+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the last line has a newline at the end, just like every other line; that gives the appearance of a last blank line when viewed in an editor. That shouldn't have any effect on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileinput` library and `strip()` function to remove blank lines, like

```
import fileinput
lines = [line.strip() for line in fileinput.FileInput("test3.dat") ]
```

or you can use the `isspace()` function, like

```
lines = [line for line in fileinput.FileInput("test3.dat") if not line.isspace()]
```